# Visual Studio 2022 for Mac Manage Branches and Remotes window missing buttons

Tags: git, macos, version-control, visual-studio-2022, visual-studio-mac

I'm using Visual Studio 2022 version 17.6 (build 1575).  On the menu Git -> Manage Branches and Remotes" window the buttons New, Edit, Delete & Switch Brach are missing. The product article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/working-with-git?view=vsmac-2022#switching-branches shows these buttons.

Has anyone come across this issue?

[image: Manage Branches and Remotes]

Editing to add Branches tab screenshot.[image]

Thanks.

Comment: You look to be on the "Remote Sources" tab - the images for the link you included seem to be on the "branches" tab.  What happens if you switch to that tab?

Comment: @TimothyG. I have edited the post to add Branches tab screenshot.  It is definitely different from what is shown in the article.  I have submitted an issue with GitHub and requested them to add instructions for how to switch branches in VS2022.

Comment: To whoever gave negative vote, I don't get why you did that.  If you are using VS2022 on Mac you will understand the issue with the information I have provided.  Anyway thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Visual Studio for Mac 17.6 the Manage Branches and Remotes dialog has changed. In order to create a branch, and have it track a remote, select the Branches tab and can click the New button. In the dialog that opens enter the branch name, then select the remote branch from the drop down.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, MS has posted the same response.  These new changes are not documented yet so it is bit unclear.  Also why do we have enter the branch name? It should be always the feature branch name?  Anyways, now I'm able to checkout and switch to remote branches locally.  Thank you.

Comment: The branch name may not necessarily match the remote branch name. You could be creating a feature branch based on the remote branch, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is a product issue.  It has been reported to Microsoft https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/checkout--track-remote-branch-localy---/10397619